# How to parse JSON when there are NULL values inside?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse JSON data, but when I have NULL in some branches of JSON Python gives me an error:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

This situation is OK:

```py
import json

x = '''[{"address":{"city": "city1","street": "street1"}},
        {"address":{"city": "city2","street": "street2"}}]'''
source = json.loads(x)
data = []
for s in source:
    data.append([s['address']['city'],
                 s['address']['street']])
print(data)
```

And this one gives me an error:

```py
import json

x = '''[{"address":{"city": "city1","street": "street1"}},
        {"address": null},
        {"address":{"city": "city2","street": "street2"}}]'''
source = json.loads(x)
data = []
for s in source:
    data.append([s['address']['city'],
                 s['address']['street']])
print(data)
```

I would like to get NULL (None) values in the second case. What is the shortest way to do it?

**Update #1:**
I have a lot of other data, not only "address" and any of them can also be NULL. That is why I can't use "`if` statements" (there are will be too many different combinations)

**Update #2:**
To make my question more clear (in real case I have 25 different parameters, not 3 as below):

```
[
    {
        "address": {
            "city": "city1",
            "street": "street1"
        },
        "car": null,
        "person": {
            "age": "30",
            "name": "John"
        }
    },
    {
        "address": null,
        "car": {
            "color": "red",
            "year": "2015"
        },
        "person": {
            "age": "31",
            "name": "Peter"
        }
    },
    {
        "address": {
            "city": "city2",
            "street": "street2"
        },
        "car": {
            "color": "green",
            "year": "2017"
        },
        "person": null
    }
]

    data.append(   [s['address']['city'],
                    s['address']['street'],
                    s['person']['name'],
                    s['paerson']['age'],
                    s['car']['year'],
                    s['car']['color']])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generalized way to handle the situation when you have JSON objects nested one-level deep that might have NULL values. It makes use of the optional `object_hook=` keyword argument to pass a callback function to `json.loads()` (as does [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)). In this case, the function converts any `None` values in the upper-level `dict`s into empty `NoneDict` dictionary subclass instances.

`NoneDict`s simply return `None` as the value of missing keys instead of raising `KeyError`s. Optimization note: If you never change these objects — i.e. they're read-only — you really only need create is a single global instance and always use it in the `convertor()` function.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


class NoneDict(dict):
    """ dict subclass that returns a value of None for missing keys instead
        of raising a KeyError. Note: doesn't add item to dictionary.
    """
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return None


def converter(decoded_dict):
    """ Convert any None values in decoded dict into empty NoneDict's. """
    return {k: NoneDict() if v is None else v for k,v in decoded_dict.items()}

# The following JSON data is equivalent to what you have in Update #2 of your
# question, it's just formatted more compactly.
x = '''
    [{"address": {"city": "city1", "street": "street1"},
      "car": null,
      "person": {"age": "30", "name": "John"}},
     {"address": null,
      "car": {"color": "red", "year": "2015"},
      "person": {"age": "31", "name": "Peter"}},
     {"address": {"city": "city2", "street": "street2"},
      "car": {"color": "green", "year": "2017"},
      "person": null}]
'''

source = json.loads(x, object_hook=converter)
data = []

for s in source:
    data.append([s['address']['city'],
                 s['address']['street'],
                 s['person']['name'],
                 s['person']['age'],
                 s['car']['year'],
                 s['car']['color']])

pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
[['city1', 'street1', 'John', '30', None, None],
 [None, None, 'Peter', '31', '2015', 'red'],
 ['city2', 'street2', None, None, '2017', 'green']]
```

Note that the part near the very end could be written like this to make it more "data-driven":

```
items = (('address', 'city'),
         ('address', 'street'),
         ('person', 'name'),
         ('person', 'age'),
         ('car', 'year'),
         ('car', 'color'))

for s in source:
    data.append([s[k1][k2] for k1, k2 in items])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really cool! Also thanks for showing pprint module! It is very usefull for me.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `None` case separately:

```
for s in source:
    address = s['address']

    data.append(
       [None, None] if address is None
       else [address['city'], address['street']]
    )
```

Comment: Please, see for UPDATE#1

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check if address is none before trying to access things from it.
For example:

```
for s in source:
    if s['address']:
        data.append([s['address']['city]',s['address']['street']])
    else:
        # whatever behaviour you want for None values
```

Comment: if you want to be extra explicit, you can swap the if for "if not s['address'] is None"

Comment: Please, see for UPDATE#1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the second case s['address'] evaluates to None and it's not subscriptable. You should check that the value is not None and handle that case separately:

```
import json

x = '''[{"address":{"city": "city1","street": "street1"}},
        {"address": null},
        {"address":{"city": "city2","street": "street2"}}]'''                          
source = json.loads(x)
data = []
for s in source:
    if s['address'] is not None:
        data.append([s['address']['city'],
                     s['address']['street']])
    else:
        data.append(None)
print(data)
```

This will print: `[['city1', 'street1'], None, ['city2', 'street2']]`

**Edit:**
Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(source)
df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
data = df[[column for column in df.columns if '.' in column]]
print(data.values.tolist())
```

**Output:**
[['city1', 'street1', None, None, '30', 'John'], [None, None, 'red', '2015', '31', 'Peter'], ['city2', 'street2', 'green', '2017', None, None]]

Comment: Please, see for UPDATE#1

Comment: The problem is that the end result is not clear? What are you trying to accomplish exactly? json.loads already changes Null to None but you seem to be trying to make the result a list instead of a dictionary, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make a list. Also I want to add less lines to my code, because I have a lot of parameters (see my update #2)

Comment: Thank's, it works too. But in my case, I need explicitly define which parameters I want to get, because I don't need all. That is why `martineau` answer is more generalized.